# SocialEngine widget load delay

Tags: widget, socialengine

On my SocialEngine site I have a widget called photostrip it loads all photos that a member has onto the members profile page. I set the widget to load 20 photos and the members profile page loads fast, but if I set the widget to load say 200 photos it take a long time to load, it does load but takes its time to do so. I want to set a delay on when the widget will load, that will give the members profile time to load first then after say 3-5 seconds the widget can load.

My question is how do I set it so the widget will have a time delay before it loads? Is this possible?

Comment: You should add to your widget js code. And load it content by js ( make ajax request, for example ). To give more concretive answer i must to see your code